Adding security to paths in openapi.yaml 3.0.0 breaks connexion 3.1.0 Flask app requests - no auth header
I have a feeling that my flask and connexion implementation is wrong. In my 3.0.0 openapi.yaml:
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
paths:
  /api/listings:
    get:
      summary: Get user listings
      operationId: app.routes.get_listings
      security: <------------- ADDING THIS MEANS ROUTES ARE NOT PROCESSED
        - bearerAuth: [] 
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Successful response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                additionalProperties: true

I'm using flask and connexion in init.py like this:
import connexion
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask import send_from_directory, jsonify, current_app, Flask
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import sys
from flask_migrate import Migrate
import logging
from config import Config
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

load_dotenv()

db = SQLAlchemy()
jwt = JWTManager()
login_manager = LoginManager()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    with app.app_context():
        connexion_app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='../')
        app = connexion_app.app
        app.config.from_object(Config)
        
        app.config['JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION'] = ['headers']
        app.config['JWT_HEADER_NAME'] = 'Authorization'
        app.config['JWT_HEADER_TYPE'] = 'Bearer'

        current_app.logger.info(f"__init__.py -- current working directory: {os.getcwd()}")
        current_app.logger.info(f"__init__.py -- database URI: {app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']}")

        db.init_app(app)
        migrate.init_app(app, db)
        jwt.init_app(app)
        login_manager.init_app(app)

        CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {
            "origins": ["http://localhost:3000"],
            "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
            "allow_headers": ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
            "supports_credentials": True
        }}, expose_headers=["Authorization"])

        app.register_error_handler(Exception, handle_exception)

        with app.app_context():
            try:
                db.create_all()
                current_app.logger.info("__init__.py -- database tables created successfully.")
            except Exception as e:
                current_app.logger.error(f"__init__.py -- an error occurred creating database tables: {e}")

        from . import routes

        import inspect
        for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(routes):
            if inspect.isfunction(obj):
                current_app.logger.debug(f"__init__.py -- function found in routes: {name}")

        def connexion_debug(function_name):
            function = getattr(routes, function_name.split('.')[-1], None)
            if function is None:
                current_app.logger.error(f"__init__.py -- function {function_name} not found in routes")
            else:
                current_app.logger.debug(f"__init__.py -- function {function_name} found in routes: {function}")
            return function

        connexion_app.add_api('openapi.yaml', resolver=connexion_debug)

        @app.route('/')
        @cross_origin(origins="http://localhost:3000")
        def serve(path):
            if path != "" and os.path.exists(app.static_folder + '/' + path):
                return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, path)
            else:
                return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')

        return app

Am I using connexion wrong here?!
If I omit the security from the openapi spec, then my routes work fine, the jwt is present and can be used, I see these log messages:
@jwt_required()
def get_listings():
    current_app.logger.debug("routes.py -- Entering get_listings function")

    try:
        current_user_id = get_jwt_identity() <-------- WITHOUT SECURITY IN OPENAPI THIS IS OKAY SO IS CONNEXION MISCONFIGURED??
        current_app.logger.debug(f"routes.py -- request get_listings received - user ID: {current_user_id}")
        if not current_user_id:
            return jsonify({"msg": "Invalid token"}), 401
        else:
            current_app.logger.debug(f"routes.py -- current user ID: {current_user_id}")

        listings = Listing.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user_id).all()
        return jsonify([listing.to_dict() for listing in listings]), 200
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        current_app.logger.error(f"routes.py -- database error while fetching listings: {str(e)}")
        return jsonify({"msg": "An error occurred while fetching listings"}), 500
    except Exception as e:
        current_app.logger.error(f"routes.py --  request get_listings: Unexpected error while fetching listings: {str(e)}")
        jsonify({"msg": "Ahhhh!!!!"}), 500

But if I include the security in the openapi spec, NOTHING IS LOGGED. I just get 401
So does this mean that the connexion processing of requests is not including the auth header?
I only see this error in the python debug console:
2024-07-31 11:41:24,921 INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2024 11:41:24] "GET /api/listings HTTP/1.1" 401 - [in /me/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/werkzeug/_internal.py:224]
browser console logs:
Headers before Axios request: {Authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJmcm…4MzR9.Ot76Mxs3loesFTqqctd0Vj3n7qgiA_woQfunZM2TU1Q', Content-Type: 'application/json'}
 
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/listings 401 (UNAUTHORIZED)

11:41:24.897 MyListings.tsx:47 MyListings.tsx: Axios error: Request failed with status code 401

11:41:24.897 MyListings.tsx:48 Response data: {detail: 'No authorization token provided', status: 401, title: 'Unauthorized', type: 'about:blank'}

something is removing/not handling the token and i believe it's connexion
I am using connexion 3.1.0
because I don't see anything logged on the route, I think the request is not being processed and is being rejected between axios and connexion.
CORS is setup okay I believe, since without the security spec in openapi I don't get CORS errors
